# Java classcastexception

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("\n1: Enter Promotion Package ID: ");
int id = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
if(PromotionDB.searchPackage(id)!=null) {
    OrderDB.createItem(id);
}
```

I have a code like this as my application and I wan to reference from my PromotionDB class and check for the ID, if the ID is valid, den I pass the ID to my OrderDB class which goes to the code:

```
public static void createItem(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String name = "",description = "";
    Float cost= (float) 0;

    try {
        al = readPromotion(filename) ;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < al.size() ; i++) {
            OrderForm set = (OrderForm)al.get(i);
            if(set.getid() == id){
                name = set.getname();
                description = set.getdescription();
                cost = set.getcost();
                break;
            }
        }

        OrderForm p1 = new OrderForm(id, name, description, cost);
        al.add(p1);
        savePromotionPackages(filename2, al);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("IOException > " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

But I received a ClassCastException, can anyone explain to me why? I am fairly new to programming

Comment: Apparently `al.get(i)` is returning something other than an `OrderForm`.

Comment: This is why raw types are so bad. The actual problem probably happens in `readPromotion` where you put something wrong in the List but the error has trickled up in to seemingly unrelated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about the exception in the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html).

From the docs:

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance. For example, the following code generates a ClassCastException:

```
Object x = new Integer(0);
System.out.println((String)x);
```

You seem to be attempting the same error with your line:

```
OrderForm set = (OrderForm)al.get(i);
```

To fix your code you need to have `readPromotion` return `List<OrderForm>`.

Comment: My readpromotion return an arraylist:
ArrayList alr = new ArrayList() ;

Comment: @JordanIatro What type of objects are you putting in this ArrayList?

Comment: @JordanIatro Avoid raw types if possible. Change that line of code to `ArrayList<OrderForm> alr = new ArrayList<>();`. Your compiler can now check if you try to insert something different than an `OrderForm` into that list.

Comment: Ok. I understand the code better. readPromotion needs to return a list of OrderForms. I'll edit my answer